# USB keyboard unplugs and plugs itself when a human approaches or steps away

Tags: usb, usb-device

My computer makes the USB disconnect/connect sound whenever I stand up and walk away from the desk or sometimes sit down at the desk. I tracked down the source, which is the keyboard, by testing with it enabled and disabled multiple times. I also confirmed it using the software USBLogView to track USB device activity.

When looking up this problem, I've found that other people have also experienced this issue. Examples:

https://www.sevenforums.com/sound-audio/283251-my-computer-knows-when-i-go-walk-away-7.html
https://forum.quartertothree.com/t/my-computer-is-haunted/78433

Video included in the 2nd link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0ksE7g8nkA

In my case, I haven't had any loss of functionality of the keyboard because it immediately plugs back in after unplugging itself.

What could be causing this and how would I fix it?

Comment: Is this a wireless keyboard that works with a "dongle" plugged into a USB port? Or a plain old wired USB keyboard?

Comment: @MarkLeavitt It's a wired USB keyboard.

Comment: probably the cable is broken or the plug is loose.

Comment: Sorry, but product debug/repair/usage questions are not on topic here.  This site is only for design questions and those questions for which design-level technical detail is available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low-speed USB devices are allowed to have their cable to be unshielded. Some makers use these cheaper cables to reduce device's cost and have more flexible (user-friendly) cables. These cables are prone to external radio interference, including small ESD events that always happen, especially in dry-air winter time. With unshielded cable all interference goes straight into signal ground and causes USB disconnect event, and, since the cable/device is still there (connected), the driver will immediately re-enumerate the device. The effect also depends on how the USB connector shield is grounded on mainboard of PC, to the chassis or straight to signal ground.

Get a better keyboard and/or better PC.